# Переопределить репозиторий пакета в composer

Tags: php, composer

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой.

В моем проекте через `composer` подключается пакет [nodge/yii-eauth](https://github.com/Nodge/yii-eauth). При выполнении `composer update` выдает [404-ую ошибку](https://github.com/Nodge/yii-eauth/issues/116#issue-319521998). Если я правильно понял, пакет `nodge/yii-eauth` внутри себя подключает другой пакет `itmages/yii-eoauth`, а тот по какой-то причине удален с github-а

Добрые люди [сделали копию](https://github.com/Nodge/yii-eauth/issues/116#issuecomment-391724703) удаленного репозитория. Подскажите, какие мне изменения внести в мой `composer.json`, чтоб когда скачивался пакет `nodge/yii-eauth`, а для него скачивалась зависимость `itmages/yii-eoauth`, эта самая зависимость бралась из стороннего репозитория (чтоб я мог указать, из какого репозитория ее брать)

Comment: А что у вас в настоящий момент описано в composer.json касательно данной темы?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

1. Склонировать пакет `nodge/yii-eauth` в приватный репозиторий или форкнуть на гитхабе.
2. Править `composer.json`, в секции require поменять удаленные пакеты на восстановленные, закомитить правки (лучше в отдельную ветку, например - `hotfix`).

**composer.json:**

```
"require": {
    ...,
    "nodge/yii-eauth": "^1.2",
    "sizeg/itmages-lightopenid": "dev-master",
    "sizeg/itmages-yii-eoauth": "dev-master",
    ...
}
```

3. Править `composer.json` у вашего проекта - добавить в него ваш приватный VCS-репозиторий со ссылкой на `nodge/yii-eauth`.

**composer.json:**

```
"require": {
        "nodge/yii-eauth": "dev-hotfix"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://your.private.vcs/nodge/yii-eauth"
        }
    ]
```

4. Выполнить `composer update nodge/yii-eauth` для вашего проекта